# Determine controllerAs Syntax from the Controller

Tags: angularjs

The `ng-controller` directive has two ways of instantiating a controller. Vanilla and `controller as` syntax. How can a controller determine which way it was invoked and adjust its behavior accordingly?

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="myController" >
   <p> {{message}} World </p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="myController as myVm">
   <p> {{myVm.message}} World </p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="myController as otherVm">
   <p> {{otherVm.message}} World </p>
</div>
```

How can I make this work in my controller?

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", function($scope) {

    function usesClassSyntax() {
        //what do i put here?
        return true/false
    };

    if (usesClassSyntax()) {
         var vm = this;
    } else {
         var vm = $scope;
    };

    vm.message = "Hello";
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

by using controller as syntax we just create a new variable in our scope..

```js
angular.module("myApp").controller("myController", function($scope) {

  function usesClassSyntax() {
    //i think this will help
    if (typeof $scope.myVm != 'undefined')
      return true;
    else
      return false
  };

  if (usesClassSyntax()) {
    var vm = this;
  } else {
    var vm = $scope;
  };

  vm.message = "Hello";
});
```

Comment: That only works for `controller as myVm`. What if the contoller is instantiated with a different name. Say `controller as otherVm`?

Comment: You can pass `controller as` name to controller and check for it

Comment: @CodeBean correct me if I'm but that'll only work if the controller was explicitly declared in the DOM.  If you're using something like ui.router or the like, it will not work in that fashion, at least to my knowledge.  Regardless though, if you are consistent with your naming convention, you can reuse the same "controller as" name.  I use `vc` for every view controller and only in very rare instances do you get nested `vc`s

Comment: I think this blog post can give you some directions .. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2852-understanding-how-to-use-scope-watch-with-controller-as-in-angularjs.htm